# screenshot large pdf from web browser and save out to pdf webpage screenshot

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, browser, screenshot, webpage-screenshot

I have a large pdf file (1000 pages) which I am viewing in chrome.  I'm not able to download the pdf or print it or do anything else with it.  Only view it in a browser.
Is there a way of screen shotting the entire document and saving to a pdf file?
Grateful in advance for any ideas on how to do this.